# Microservice consuming from and publishing to RabbitMQ under Spring Transaction - provides exactly once guarantee?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-transactions, exactly-once, reliable-message-delivery

I have a microservice consuming a message from RabbitMQ queue 1 and publishing it to RabbitMQ queue 2. If this microservice wraps these two operations under Spring @Transactional annotation, would it provide exactly-once or at-least-once delivery guarantee? If it's at-least-once, what is the condition which would disrupt exactly-once making it at-least-once?